# Shorter way to write this code

Tags: haskell, if-statement, combinators, option-type

The following pattern appears very frequently in Haskell code. Is there a shorter way to write it?

```
if pred x
then Just x
else Nothing
```

Comment: Maybe you could post some context code showing how it's common? There might be a way to rewrite the code that's using it...

Comment: As [Petr Pudlák indicates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24657578/1477667), `Control.Monad.Plus` from `monadplus` offers a `partial` function to do just this. A more general one would be `bool empty . pure <*> id`

Answer (score 28):

You're looking for [`mfilter` in `Control.Monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3amfilter):

```
mfilter :: MonadPlus m => (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m a

-- mfilter odd (Just 1) == Just 1
-- mfilter odd (Just 2) == Nothing
```

Note that if the condition doesn't depend on the content of the `MonadPlus`, you can write instead:

```
"foo" <$ guard (odd 3) -- Just "foo"
"foo" <$ guard (odd 4) -- Nothing
```

Comment: It might be worst to rewrite the OP problem using `mfilter`, ie : `mfilter pred (Just x)`.

Answer (score 7):

Hm... You are looking for a combinator that takes an `a`, a function `a -> Bool` and returns a `Maybe a`. Stop! [Hoogle time](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+Maybe+a). There is no complete match, but `find` is quite close:

```
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
```

I doubt that you can actually find your function somewhere. But why not define it by yourself?

```
ifMaybe :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe a
ifMaybe f a | f a = Just a
ifMaybe _ _       = Nothing
```

Comment: Using `find`, you can write `ifMaybe = (. return) . find`. Substitute `mfilter` instead of `find` to have it work on any `MonadPlus`.

Comment: @is7s: I'm not sure what you mean. The type will be `MonadPlus m => (a -> Bool) -> a -> m a`. If true, the result will be `return x`, if not, it will be `mzero`.

Comment: +1 for Stop! Hoogle time. :) Notice Landei's answer, just plain old `mfilter`, is the fourth hit.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
(?:) (5>2) (Just 5,Nothing)
```

from Data.Bool.HT.

Comment: ooooo... that's neat. Never have looked at that module.  Thanks!

Comment: I believe it's meant to be used infix: `(5 > 2) ?: (Just 5, Nothing)`

Comment: I don't really see what this offers above and beyond `if`/`then`/`else`, besides saving a couple of characters; you're still unnecessarily repeating the `5` term, and having to mention `Nothing`. The `mfilter` solution is superior.

Comment: Using the `utility-ht` package you can use `toMaybe` instead of `(?:)` => `toMaybe (pred x) x`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `guard` to achieve this behavior:

```
guard (pred x) >> return x
```

This is such a generally useful behavior that I've even defined `ensure` in my own little suite of code for one-offs (everybody has such a thing, right? ;-):

```
ensure p x = guard (p x) >> return x
```

Comment: Slightly more general: `ensure p x = x <$ guard (p x)` where `<$` is from `Control.Applicative`.

Slightly more pointfree: `ensure p = ap (<$) (guard . p)` :)

Comment: @benmachine Is that really more general? `guard` already requires `MonadPlus`, so you still can't use your `ensure` on non-monadic applicatives.

Comment: Oh, good point. If I really wanted I could make it require `Alternative` instead, but it's probably not worth it :)

`<$` is still cuter, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
f pred x = if pred x then Just x else Nothing
```

Given the above definition, you can simply write:

```
f pred x
```

Of course this is no different than Daniel Wagner's `ensure` or FUZxxl's `ifMaybe`. But it's name is simply `f`, making it the shortest, and it's definition is precisely the code you gave, making it the most easily proven correct. ;)

Some ghci, just for fun

```
ghci> let f pred x = if pred x then Just x else Nothing
ghci> f (5>) 2
Just 2
ghci> f (5>) 6
Nothing
```

If you couldn't tell, this isn't a very serious answer. The others are a bit more insightful, but I couldn't resist the tongue-in-cheek response to "make this code shorter".

Answer (score 1):

Usually I'm a big fan of very generic code, but I actually find this exact function useful often enough, specialized to `Maybe`, that I keep it around instead of using `guard`, `mfilter`, and the like.

The name I use for it is `justIf`, and I'd typically use it for doing things like this:

```
∀x. x ⊢ import Data.List
∀x. x ⊢ unfoldr (justIf (not . null . snd) . splitAt 3) [1..11]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Basically, stuff where some sort of element-wise filtering or checking needs to be done in a compound expression, so `Maybe` is used to indicate the result of the predicate.

For the specialized version like this, there really isn't much you can do to make it shorter. It's already pretty simple. There's a fine line between being concise, and just golfing your code for character count, and for something this simple I wouldn't really worry about trying to "improve" it...

Comment: @hammar: Hahahaha. The spreading popularity of using `λ>` inspired me to change mine, and... I guess it seemed like a good idea at the time?