# Folding across Maybes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

In an attempt to learn Haskell, I have come across a situation in which I wish to do a fold over a list but my accumulator is a Maybe. The function I'm folding with however takes in the "extracted" value in the Maybe and if one fails they all fail. I have a solution I find kludgy, but knowing as little Haskell as I do, I believe there should be a better way. Say we have the following toy problem: we want to sum a list, but fours for some reason are bad, so if we attempt to sum in a four at any time we want to return Nothing. My current solution is as follows:

```
import Maybe

explodingFourSum :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
explodingFourSum numberList =
    foldl explodingFourMonAdd (Just 0) numberList
    where explodingFourMonAdd =
        (\x y -> if isNothing x
                    then Nothing
                    else explodingFourAdd (fromJust x) y)

explodingFourAdd :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
explodingFourAdd _ 4 = Nothing
explodingFourAdd x y = Just(x + y)
```

So basically, is there a way to clean up, or eliminate, the lambda in the `explodingFourMonAdd` using some kind of Monad fold? Or somehow currying in the >>=
operator so that the fold behaves like a list of functions chained by >>=?

Comment: BTW, the module `Maybe` is deprecated. Use `Data.Maybe` if possible.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you can use [foldM](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM)

```
explodingFourSum numberList = foldM explodingFourAdd 0 numberList
```

This lets you get rid of the extra lambda *and* that (Just 0) in the beggining.

---

BTW, check out [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle) to search around for functions you don't really remember the name for.

Comment: Yes, `foldM explodingFourAdd 0` should be exactly the same. This sort of thing is what `foldM` is there for.

Comment: @C. A. McCann: Murphy's law prevents me from being that certain withou an interpreter at hand. That said, I'm editing my answer now :)

Comment: @missingno: I nearly always test in GHCi before posting an answer. I'm certain in this case because you wrote your answer while I was testing mine. ;] I've learned the hard way to check first, especially where some of the monadic lifting functions are concerned. `foldM` is actually not the monadic fold I usually want (and sometimes forgetfully think it is).

Answer (score 6):

> So basically, is there a way to clean up, or eliminate, the lambda in the explodingFourMonAdd using some kind of Monad fold?

Yapp. In Control.Monad there's the `foldM` function, which is exactly what you want here. So you can replace your call to `foldl` with `foldM explodingFourAdd 0 numberList`.

Answer (score 5):

You can exploit the fact, that `Maybe` is a monad. The function `sequence :: [m a] -> m [a]` has the following effect, if `m` is `Maybe`: If all elements in the list are `Just x` for some `x`, the result is a list of all those justs. Otherwise, the result is `Nothing`.

So you first decide for all elements, whether it is a failure. For instance, take your example:

```
foursToNothing :: [Int] -> [Maybe Int]
foursToNothing = map go where
  go 4 = Nothing
  go x = Just x
```

Then you run sequence and `fmap` the fold:

```
explodingFourSum = fmap (foldl' (+) 0) . sequence . foursToNothing
```

Of course you have to adapt this to your specific case.

Comment: On second reading, I like this solution a lot: it separates the "check for fours" phase from the "sum" phase, plus it looks like it has a chance of playing nicely with the garbage collector. Cool! I would change the `sequence . map` to `mapM`, though: `explodingFourSum = fmap sum . mapM (ensure (/=4))`. (See [ensure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453744/shorter-way-to-write-this-code/7455473#7455473)'s definition.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's another possibility not mentioned by other people. You can separately check for fours and do the sum:

```
import Control.Monad
explodingFourSum xs = guard (all (/=4) xs) >> return (sum xs)
```

That's the entire source. This solution is beautiful in a lot of ways: it reuses a lot of already-written code, and it nicely expresses the two important facts about the function (whereas the other solutions posted here mix those two facts up together).

Of course, there is at least one good reason *not* to use this implementation, as well. The other solutions mentioned here traverse the input list only once; this interacts nicely with the garbage collector, allowing only small portions of the list to be in memory at any given time. This solution, on the other hand, traverses `xs` twice, which will prevent the garbage collector from collecting the list during the first pass.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your toy example that way, too:

```
import Data.Traversable

explodingFour 4 = Nothing 
explodingFour x = Just x

explodingFourSum = fmap sum . traverse explodingFour
```

Of course this works only because *one* value is enough to know when the calculation fails. If the failure condition depends on *both* values x and y in `explodingFourSum`, you need to use `foldM`.

BTW: A fancy way to write `explodingFour` would be

```
import Control.Monad

explodingFour x = mfilter (/=4) (Just x)
```

This trick works for `explodingFourAdd` as well, but is less readable:

```
explodingFourAdd x y = Just (x+) `ap` mfilter (/=4) (Just y)
```