# Does this Bool-producer to Maybe-producer function appear in any common library?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I found myself wanting this tiny little function, but it doesn't seem to be in `Data.Maybe`. Is it somewhere else?

```
splat :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe a
splat c a
  | c a       = Just a
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: http://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle is more comprehensive than http://www.haskell.org/hoogle. The only function I could find would be if you made a `Foldable` instance for `Identity`, you could use `find :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Maybe a`! ;)

Comment: Or `splat = mfilter . fmap (. return)`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453744/shorter-way-to-write-this-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package [monadplus](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monadplus) contains exactly this function, named [`partial`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monadplus-1.4.2/docs/Control-Monad-Plus.html#v%3apartial):

```
partial :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe a
```

Answer (score 7):

```
splat :: MonadPlus m => (a -> Bool) -> a -> m a
splat c x = guard (c x) >> return x
```

would be a shorter, more general definition, if you decided you want this. But just using `guard` in-line wherever you need it is likely to be more convenient anyway.

Comment: Sorry to take back the accept, but as nice as your answer is, the other one was precisely on point, so I didn't feel I had much choice.